# Table Cells get attached to top

Tags: ios, swift

If i test the app on large screen simulator everything works well, but the moment i test the code in small screen simulator, there is no error but the cells that are not visible and can be seen only while scrolling gets attached to top of screen, strangely enough if i scroll down again i can see the labels and text fields looking like they are moving from top to their original locations, but they do not and remain on screen top, i am posting the image , where could i be making the mistake below is code of file and image , the misbehaviour happens when i scroll

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class RestaurantAddController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate, UITextViewDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate & UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    
    
    
    let displayInputForm = UITableView()
    var restaurant: Restaurant!
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 6
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = displayInputForm.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String(describing: RestaurantAddViewCells.self), for: indexPath) as! RestaurantAddViewCells
        cell.heightAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 100).isActive = true
        view.addSubview(cell)
        //   view.addSubview(cell.contentView)
        view.addSubview(cell.imageToUpload)
        view.addSubview(cell.nameToUploadLabel)
        view.addSubview(cell.nameToUploadTextField)
        view.addSubview(cell.typeToUploadLabel)
        view.addSubview(cell.typeToUploadTextField)
        view.addSubview(cell.locationToUploadLabel)
        view.addSubview(cell.locationToUploadTextField)
        view.addSubview(cell.phoneToUploadLabel)
        view.addSubview(cell.phoneToUPloadTextField)
        view.addSubview(cell.summartyToUploadLabel)
        view.addSubview(cell.summaryToUploadTextView)
        //Add to cell via stackView
        let stackEntry = UIStackView()
        view.addSubview(stackEntry)
        stackEntry.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stackEntry.alignment = .top
        stackEntry.axis = .vertical
        stackEntry.spacing = 5.0
        stackEntry.distribution = .fill
        
        stackEntry.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        stackEntry.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
        stackEntry.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        //add scroll view
        //        let scrollView = UIScrollView()
        //        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        //        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        //        scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: displayInputForm.topAnchor).isActive = true
        //        scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: displayInputForm.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        //        scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: displayInputForm.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        //        scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: displayInputForm.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        //        scrollView.addSubview(stackEntry)
        //MARK:- give custom font
        let font = UIFont(name: "Rubik-Medium", size: 18)
        let fontMetrics = UIFontMetrics(forTextStyle: .body)
        
        let labels = [cell.locationToUploadLabel, cell.typeToUploadLabel, cell.nameToUploadLabel, cell.phoneToUploadLabel, cell.summartyToUploadLabel]
        labels.forEach { label in
            label.font = fontMetrics.scaledFont(for: font!)
        }
        
        
        let textCusotm = [cell.nameToUploadTextField, cell.typeToUploadTextField, cell.locationToUploadTextField, cell.phoneToUPloadTextField]
        textCusotm.forEach { (fields) in
            fields.font = fontMetrics.scaledFont(for: font!)
            
        }
        cell.summaryToUploadTextView.font = fontMetrics.scaledFont(for: font!)
        
        //MARK:- add cell per row
        switch indexPath.row {
            
        case 0:
            
            cell.heightAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 250).isActive = true
            let buttonImage = UIImageView()
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
            buttonImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            buttonImage.image = UIImage(named: "photo")
            view.addSubview(buttonImage)
            buttonImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
            buttonImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
            
            buttonImage.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
            
            buttonImage.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
            
            return cell
        case 1:
            cell.selectionStyle = .none
            cell.nameToUploadLabel.text = "Name of Hotel:"
            cell.nameToUploadTextField.placeholder = "Enter Hotel Name"
            cell.nameToUploadTextField.tag = 1
            cell.nameToUploadTextField.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
            stackEntry.addArrangedSubview(cell.nameToUploadLabel)
            stackEntry.addArrangedSubview(cell.nameToUploadTextField)
            //   cell.nameToUploadTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
            cell.nameToUploadTextField.delegate = self
            return cell
            
            
        case 2:
            cell.selectionStyle = .none
            
            cell.typeToUploadLabel.text = "Type Of Hotel:"
            cell.typeToUploadTextField.placeholder = "Name type of hotel"
            cell.typeToUploadTextField.tag = 2
            cell.typeToUploadTextField.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
            stackEntry.addArrangedSubview(cell.typeToUploadLabel)
            stackEntry.addArrangedSubview(cell.typeToUploadTextField)
            cell.typeToUploadTextField.delegate = self
            return cell
            
        case 3:
            cell.selectionStyle = .none
            cell.locationToUploadLabel.text = "Location of Hotel:"
            cell.locationToUploadTextField.placeholder = "Enter Hotel Location"
            cell.locationToUploadTextField.tag = 3
            cell.locationToUploadTextField.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
            stackEntry.addArrangedSubview(cell.locationToUploadLabel)
            stackEntry.addArrangedSubview(cell.locationToUploadTextField)
            cell.locationToUploadTextField.delegate = self
            return cell
            
        case 4:
            cell.selectionStyle = .none
            cell.phoneToUploadLabel.text = "Phone:"
            cell.phoneToUPloadTextField.placeholder = "Enter Phone"
            cell.phoneToUPloadTextField.tag = 4
            cell.phoneToUPloadTextField.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
            stackEntry.addArrangedSubview(cell.phoneToUploadLabel)
            stackEntry.addArrangedSubview(cell.phoneToUPloadTextField)
            cell.phoneToUPloadTextField.delegate = self
            return cell
            
        case 5:
            cell.selectionStyle = .none
            cell.summartyToUploadLabel.text = "Enter Summary:"
            //cell.summaryToUploadTextView.place
            cell.summaryToUploadTextView.tag = 5
            cell.summaryToUploadTextView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
            cell.summaryToUploadTextView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 20).isActive = true
            cell.summaryToUploadTextView.layer.borderWidth = 1
            cell.summaryToUploadTextView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
            cell.summaryToUploadTextView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
            stackEntry.addArrangedSubview(cell.summartyToUploadLabel)
            stackEntry.addArrangedSubview(cell.summaryToUploadTextView)
            cell.summaryToUploadTextView.delegate = self
            return cell
            
        default:
            fatalError("No data found")
            
        }
    }
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        displayInputForm.delegate = self
        displayInputForm.dataSource = self
        //MARK:- Add scroll view
        
        view.addSubview(displayInputForm)
        
        
        
        
        let footerView = UIView()
        displayInputForm.tableFooterView = footerView
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
        //Add pinning of table
        displayInputForm.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.displayInputForm.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        self.displayInputForm.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        self.displayInputForm.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        self.displayInputForm.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        
        //Change the back button to arrow
        let imgBack = UIImage(named: "back")
        
        navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = imgBack
        navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = imgBack
        
        navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
        navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: self, action: nil)
        
        // Register a cell
        displayInputForm.register(RestaurantAddViewCells.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: String(describing: RestaurantAddViewCells.self))
        
        //MARK:- add the cancel and save button
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "close"), style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(closeRestaurant))
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "save"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(saveRestaurantData))
        
    }
    
    
    //MARK:- close function
    @objc func closeRestaurant() {
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
    
    //MARK:- save function
    @objc func saveRestaurantData() {
        
        let indexPath0 = IndexPath(row: 1, section: 0)
        let cell0 = displayInputForm.cellForRow(at: indexPath0) as! RestaurantAddViewCells
        let nameVal = cell0.nameToUploadTextField.text
        
        let indexPath1 = IndexPath(row: 2, section: 0)
        let cell1 = displayInputForm.cellForRow(at: indexPath1) as! RestaurantAddViewCells
        let typeVal = cell1.typeToUploadTextField.text
        
        let indexPath2 = IndexPath(row: 3, section: 0)
        let cell2 = displayInputForm.cellForRow(at: indexPath2) as! RestaurantAddViewCells
        let locationVal = cell2.locationToUploadTextField.text
        
        let indexPath3 = IndexPath(row: 4, section: 0)
        let cell3 = displayInputForm.cellForRow(at: indexPath3) as! RestaurantAddViewCells
        let phoneVal = cell3.phoneToUPloadTextField.text
        
        let indexPath4 = IndexPath(row: 5, section: 0)
        let cell4 = displayInputForm.cellForRow(at: indexPath4) as! RestaurantAddViewCells
        let summaryVal = cell4.summaryToUploadTextView.text
        
        
        let indexPath5 = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
        let cell5 = displayInputForm.cellForRow(at: indexPath5) as! RestaurantAddViewCells
        let imageVal = cell5.imageToUpload.image
        
        
        if (imageVal == nil || nameVal == "" || typeVal == "" || locationVal == "" || phoneVal == "" || summaryVal == "") {
            let saveAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Empty Fields", message: "Fill all the fileds", preferredStyle: .alert)
            
            let saveAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
            
            saveAlertController.addAction(saveAlertAction)
            
            self.present(saveAlertController, animated: true) {
                let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.dissMissAlertController))
                saveAlertController.view.superview?.subviews[0].addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
            }
        }
            
        else {
            if let appDelegate = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate) {
                let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
                restaurant = Restaurant(context: context)
                restaurant.name = nameVal
                restaurant.type = typeVal
                restaurant.location = locationVal
                restaurant.phone = phoneVal
                restaurant.summary = summaryVal
                
                if let restaurantImage = cell5.imageToUpload.image {
                    restaurant.image = restaurantImage.pngData()
                }
                
                print("data saved")
                appDelegate.saveContext()
            }
        }
        
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: false)
        
        
    }
    
    
    
    /*
     // MARK: - Navigation
     
     // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
     override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
     // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
     }
     */
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        
        self.title = "Add Restaurants"
        
    }
    
    
    //MARK:- check if textfield can be moved to next one on return key press
    
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        if let nextField = view.viewWithTag(textField.tag + 1) as? UITextField {
            textField.resignFirstResponder()
            nextField.becomeFirstResponder()
            //  nextField.endEditing(false)
            
        }
        
        return true
    }
    //MARK:- add sction to row clicks
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            let UIImageAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "Select an option", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
            
            let photoGalleryAction = UIAlertAction(title: "PhotoLibrary", style: .default) { (action) in
                if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.photoLibrary) {
                    let imageController = UIImagePickerController()
                    imageController.allowsEditing = false
                    imageController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
                    imageController.delegate = self
                    self.present(imageController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            }
            
            UIImageAlertController.addAction(photoGalleryAction)
            
            
            let cameraPicturesAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default) { (action) in
                if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera) {
                    let cameraController = UIImagePickerController()
                    cameraController.allowsEditing = false
                    cameraController.sourceType = .camera
                    cameraController.delegate = self
                    
                    self.present(cameraController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            }
            
            UIImageAlertController.addAction(cameraPicturesAction)
            self.present(UIImageAlertController, animated: true) {
                let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.dissMissAlertController))
                UIImageAlertController.view.superview?.subviews[0].addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
            }
        }
        
        
    }
    
    @objc func dissMissAlertController() {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    
    //MARK:- function to add and select a picture and then add it
    
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        if let selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
            if let indexPath = displayInputForm.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                let cell = displayInputForm.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! RestaurantAddViewCells
                cell.imageToUpload.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                cell.imageToUpload.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.widthAnchor).isActive = true
                cell.imageToUpload.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 250).isActive = true
                cell.imageToUpload.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.topAnchor).isActive = true
                cell.imageToUpload.image = selectedImage
                cell.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
                cell.clipsToBounds = true
                
            }
            
            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
    
    
    
}
```

[image]

**Solution**

add this line in viewdidload, where the tableName is the instance of your table

```
<tableName>.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
```

Comment: Be aware that `cellForRow` is called very often and each call adds 13(!) new subviews to the view. This looks pretty weird.

Comment: @vadian - but i add based on indexPath.row, but still the whole thing works well in larger screen , can you suggest where i am messing it up ?

Comment: @vadian - just trolling around i found a line of code that did the trick like magic , displayInputForm.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never, well after using this line,the problem is gone